# Applying multiple jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have made two jquery plugins which both work in their own right.

If I call them using:

```
$('input').inputShrink();
$('input').fillForm();
```

then the two effects work. However, if I do:

```
$('input').inputShrink().fillForm();
```

then only the first one is applied. It was my understanding you could do this, is there something in my plugins I need to set up?

Comment: are you returning the jQuery object in your first plugin?

Comment: Bingo! If you make your comment an answer I can mark it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the jQuery docs : [LINK](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

> Maintain chainability in a plugin, you must make sure your plugin returns the `this`keyword.

In short - remember to return the jQuery object in your plugin.